# Generating a New Laravel Application Key Using Cpanel SSH

Tags: laravel-5, ssh, cpanel

I want to use this command using ssh access of shared hosting.

see below

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan migrate --seed
php artisan storage:link
```

How can i do that in cpanel ssh ?

Comment: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/SSH+Access